# Create sequential dates with each date repeated multiple times

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

For every day of the year, I need the day repeated in 10 rows.  How can I accomplish this efficiently?

```
e.g.
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/01/2019
01/02/2019
01/02/2019
01/02/2019
01/02/2019
01/02/2019
01/02/2019
01/02/2019
01/02/2019
01/02/2019
01/02/2019
... (all other dates)
12/31/2019
12/31/2019
12/31/2019
12/31/2019
12/31/2019
12/31/2019
12/31/2019
12/31/2019
12/31/2019
12/31/2019
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Formula

First as a single line, then broken out into multiple lines.  Use whichever you prefer as both are valid and differences are cosmetic.

```
=TOCOL(BYROW(SEQUENCE(EOMONTH(DATE(2019, 1, 1), 11)-DATE(2019, 1, 1)+1, 1, DATE(2019, 1, 1)), LAMBDA(d, ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SEQUENCE(1, 10)/0, d)))))
```

```
=TOCOL(
   BYROW(
     SEQUENCE(EOMONTH(DATE(2019,1,1), 11)-DATE(2019,1,1)+1, 1, DATE(2019,1,1)),
     LAMBDA(d, 
       ARRAYFORMULA(
         IFERROR(
           SEQUENCE(1, 10)/0, d)))))
```

#### Using LET

Same formula as above but allows easier modification if the formula will be reused.  Only the year, `yr`, and number of repeats per date, `rpt`, need to be edited.

```
=LET(yr,2019, rpt,10, dat,DATE(yr, 1, 1), daze,EOMONTH(dat, 11)-dat+1, TOCOL(BYROW(SEQUENCE(daze, 1, dat), LAMBDA(d, ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SEQUENCE(1, rpt)/0, d))))))
```

```
=LET(
   yr,2019, rpt,10,
   dat,DATE(yr,1,1), 
   daze,EOMONTH(dat, 11)-dat+1,
   TOCOL(
     BYROW(
       SEQUENCE(daze, 1, dat),
       LAMBDA(d, 
         ARRAYFORMULA(
           IFERROR(
             SEQUENCE(1, rpt)/0, d))))))
```

## Explanation

1. A sequence of numbers is created equivalent to every date in the year 2019:

   - `365` numbers starting from `43,466` and incrementing by `1`:
   - **Note:**   `43,466 = DATE(2019, 01, 01)  = DATEVALUE(" 1/1/2019 ")`
   - EOMONTH is used to determine the last day of the month that's `11` months from `1/1/2019`: `12/31/2019`.
   - `1` is added to the difference between the two dates to return `365` days.
2. BYROW passes that 365-date number sequence row-by-row into a LAMDA function that stores the current number in `d`.
3. The LAMBDA's formula creates an array of `10` instances of `d` by creating a sequence of 10 `DIV/0` errors and IFERROR replaces each with `d`
4. TOROW takes the result of the BYROW function, an 365x10 (row x column) array and converts it to a single column, where the date changes every ten rows.

## Variation w/ MAKEARRAY

```
=LET(yr,2019, rpt,3,
  dat,DATE(yr,1,1), 
  daze,EOMONTH(dat, 11)-dat+1,
  seq,SEQUENCE(daze, 1, dat), 
    TOCOL(
      MAKEARRAY(daze, rpt,
        LAMBDA(r,c, INDEX(seq, r)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+1&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+2&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+3&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+4&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+5&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+6&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+7&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+8&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+9&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+10&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+11&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+12&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+13&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+14&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+15&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+16&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+17&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+18&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+19&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+20&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+21&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+22&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+23&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+24&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+25&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+26&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+27&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+28&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+29&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+30&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+31&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+32&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+33&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+34&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+35&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+36&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+37&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+38&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+39&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+40&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+41&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+42&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+43&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+44&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+45&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+46&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+47&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+48&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+49&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+50&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+51&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+52&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+53&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+54&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+55&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+56&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+57&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+58&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+59&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+60&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+61&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+62&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+63&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+64&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+65&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+66&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+67&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+68&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+69&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+70&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+71&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+72&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+73&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+74&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+75&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+76&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+77&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+78&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+79&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+80&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+81&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+82&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+83&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+84&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+85&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+86&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+87&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+88&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+89&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+90&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+91&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+92&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+93&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+94&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+95&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+96&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+97&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+98&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+99&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+100&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+101&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+102&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+103&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+104&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+105&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+106&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+107&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+108&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+109&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+110&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+111&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+112&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+113&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+114&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+115&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+116&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+117&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+118&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+119&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+120&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+121&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+122&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+123&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+124&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+125&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+126&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+127&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+128&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+129&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+130&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+131&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+132&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+133&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+134&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+135&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+136&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+137&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+138&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+139&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+140&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+141&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+142&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+143&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+144&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+145&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+146&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+147&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+148&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+149&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+150&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+151&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+152&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+153&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+154&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+155&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+156&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+157&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+158&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+159&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+160&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+161&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+162&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+163&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+164&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+165&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+166&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+167&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+168&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+169&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+170&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+171&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+172&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+173&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+174&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+175&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+176&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+177&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+178&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+179&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+180&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+181&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+182&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+183&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+184&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+185&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+186&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+187&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+188&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+189&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+190&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+191&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+192&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+193&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+194&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+195&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+196&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+197&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+198&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+199&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+200&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+201&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+202&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+203&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+204&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+205&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+206&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+207&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+208&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+209&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+210&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+211&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+212&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+213&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+214&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+215&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+216&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+217&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+218&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+219&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+220&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+221&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+222&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+223&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+224&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+225&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+226&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+227&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+228&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+229&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+230&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+231&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+232&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+233&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+234&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+235&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+236&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+237&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+238&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+239&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+240&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+241&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+242&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+243&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+244&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+245&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+246&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+247&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+248&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+249&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+250&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+251&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+252&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+253&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+254&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+255&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+256&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+257&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+258&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+259&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+260&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+261&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+262&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+263&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+264&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+265&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+266&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+267&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+268&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+269&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+270&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+271&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+272&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+273&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+274&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+275&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+276&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+277&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+278&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+279&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+280&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+281&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+282&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+283&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+284&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+285&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+286&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+287&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+288&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+289&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+290&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+291&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+292&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+293&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+294&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+295&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+296&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+297&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+298&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+299&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+300&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+301&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+302&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+303&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+304&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+305&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+306&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+307&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+308&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+309&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+310&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+311&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+312&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+313&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+314&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+315&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+316&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+317&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+318&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+319&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+320&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+321&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+322&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+323&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+324&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+325&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+326&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+327&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+328&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+329&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+330&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+331&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+332&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+333&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+334&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+335&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+336&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+337&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+338&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+339&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+340&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+341&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+342&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+343&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+344&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+345&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+346&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+347&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+348&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+349&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+350&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+351&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+352&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+353&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+354&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+355&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+356&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+357&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+358&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+359&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+360&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+361&"|",10)&
 REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+362&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+363&"|",10)&REPT(DATE(2019,1,1)+364&"|",10)
 ,"|",1))))
```